# CSS3 image rotation and reposition to fit in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I'll start with JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zy2xy/4/

```
<div id="page" style="position: relative; background: #ccc; width: 500px; height: 600px;">
    <div id="container" style="top: 50px; left: 100px; width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; background: #fff;"> 
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/">
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​
```

I've got a whole page div `#page`, and inside that another div `#container` positioned absolute against `#page`.

What I want to achieve, is to rotate image inside it `90deg`, `180deg` or `270deg` but always move that image to top left corner of `#container`.

I tried a little bit with `transform-origin` but I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `position:absolute` to the image

Then calculate the angle.. If it's 90 or 270 then set the left and top attributes for the image.

**Code**

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var angle = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log("angle");
    var $container = $('#container');
    var left = 0;
    var top = 0;
    if(+angle === 90 || +angle === 270){
        top = 50;
        left = -50;
    }
    $("#my_image").css({
      transform: 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
      '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
        'top' : top + 'px',
        'left' : left + 'px'
    });
}).click();​  // Fire click on DOM ready
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/zy2xy/5/)**

Comment: It's working great, but what if I had images in other sizes than 200x100 ?

Comment: @blid .. then I think you would need to calculate the positions  before hand and set them in the `css function`

Comment: Could you provide a piece of code? Because that piece of code is exacly the answer I'm looking for :)

Comment: and what about if rotation is let say 45 degree?